# Test written for mouse events failing code coverage

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine test in angular for code coverage. The test is to cover the click events of component. The test individually pass but the code coverage complains that the function is not covered.Could somebody tell me what am i missing.The tests that i an referring to here are onOverlayClicked and onDialogClicked

Component

```
export class DialogComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly _onClose = new Subject<any>();

  public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  public childComponentType: Type<any>;
  public onClose = this._onClose.asObservable();

  // add this:
  @ViewChild(InsertionDirective, { static: false })
  insertionPoint: InsertionDirective;

  constructor(public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              public cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
              public dialog: DialogRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadChildComponent(this.childComponentType);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
  }

  onOverlayClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    // close the dialog
  }

  onDialogClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }

  loadChildComponent(componentType: Type<any>) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
    const viewContainerRef = this.insertionPoint.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }
}
```

Test component

```
describe('DialogComponent', () => {
  let component: DialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, DialogModule], // DialogModule
      providers: [DialogConfig, DialogRef ]
    })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [DialogComponent, ExampleComponent] } })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.childComponentType = ExampleComponent;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set call onOverlayClicked click', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(component, 'onOverlayClicked');
    const overlay = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.overlay'));
    overlay.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.onOverlayClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });

  it('should set call onDialogClicked click', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

     spyOn(component, 'onDialogClicked');
     const overlay = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dialog'));
     overlay.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
     fixture.detectChanges();

     expect(component.onDialogClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed it

spyOn(component, 'onOverlayClicked').and.callThrough();